# Sharepoint Designer 2013 text based editor not retrieving the stages on visual designer

Tags: sharepoint, workflow, sharepoint-designer

I've been trying to create sharepoint workflow by using sharepoint designer 2013, and been creating by visual designer. I have completed the workflow on visual designer view however when I hit the publish button, I saw this error "the workflow contains errors but they are not visible in the current view." Then I realized the text based designer have not been retrieving what I've done in visual designer. I googled it but couldn't get any answer. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: If you solved this issue, please post the solution as an answer.

Comment: It may also helo **[The Workflow contains errors, but they are not visible in the current view](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/the-workflow-contains-errors-but-they-are-not-visible-in-the-current-view/)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem. It is related to order of installation of designer and MS Visio. If you face this kind of problem; uninstall both sharepoint designer and MS Visio. Install visio first, then sharepoint designer. This worked for me.

PLUS! When I installed the updates of Designer, I went back the same situation that I've asked. Updates are one of the reason of my problem.